# How can medieval peope defeat an army of volleyball-sized, armored, fire-breathing crabs?

Tags: medieval, mythical-creatures, creature-design, self-defense

In the world of Algennon humans are at a worldwide societal level equivalent to the Middle Ages. Humans also are divided into two subspecies: the Bellators (*homo sapiens bellator*) and the Plebeians (*homo sapiens communis*). [See this document for further info](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IMHkN2wNwxQzQd6z0W_HpVRXulZ04J4qKJ_U0lCQA54)

The Crabozz is a lumpy crustacean the size of a volleyball. It has four sets of legs and two pincer arms. The shell can open from the front like one of those asparagus steamers to reveal its mouth, extremely sensitive scent-antennae, and eye. It spews flaming hot jalapeño bile. The shell is very hard and spiky. Most stabbing weapons don’t work on it. The only thing bludgeons will do to it is knock it a few meters away.

*Artist's Impression* (Based on Skyrim Mudcrab)

[image]

Given this monster’s abilities and  Medieval level technology , **What strategy would medieval people use to defeat a Crabozz?**

Extra info about Crabozzes:

- Crabozzes live in gully areas by rivers or lakes, since this is where their eggs are laid.
- They can scuttle around at speeds a little less than that of a human.
- They organize in bevies of about 13-20. The females are the hunters, and the males are the brood-watchers.
- Their aggression toward humans arises from their superb sense of smell: they can smell all the delicious foods that humans make, AND all the food they’ve recently eaten. So they attack human towns as a result.

Comment: Technology wise is your universe like minecraft : Sword, shields, bow and crossbows, some TNT...? Where do they mostly live? Do they move fast? Also, are they organized in groups? If they are, how many members are they on average and do they use social survival tactics like assigning a "sentinel" role? Are they naturally aggressive towards humanoids, or more like "don't care if you don't attack"? Since you ask how to hunt them in general, all these pieces of data -and likely even more ^^'- would be very useful to know how to hunt them.

Comment: Hello Jobah. Please note that this question is a form of [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609), which are off-topic because they lack detail and are open-ended, hypothetical, all answers are of equal value, and are brainstorming (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). Sometimes OPs can avoid closure by describing in good detail one specific instance where combat occurs: the geography, disposition of troops, equipment, defenses, weapons, resources... everything. Remember, as the [help/on-topic] explains, we help you build worlds, not tell stories.

Comment: @JBH Yes, this is what I had in mind : You need to be precise yet generic enough in regards to individual characters and very specific circumstances. Not easy but you can do it! Alternatively, you can focus the question on specific points, like the most effective weapon choice to crush the carapace or favored environments to fight. Being more focused, such questions are easier to write :).

Comment: I changed it to try and meet your requirements. Sorry about the off-topicness!

Comment: I apologize, but while you've told us more about the creature, what you need to do is explain one, specific instance of combat. At this time I need to VTC for the many reasons I mentioned in my previous comment. Stack Exchange operates on a one-specific-question/one-best-answer model. Asking "how to defeat X?" without *specific combat details* can't result in one best answer.

Comment: Also to note. You haven't explained/specified the differences between Bellators and  Plebeians. What difference does it make if the village being attacked is occupied by either? Are Bellators smarter or stronger than Plebeians? Do Plebeians have better reflexes? What advantages/liabilities come into play when fighting Crabozzes if the village being attacked is occupied by either sub-race or a combination of both? Without clarification the existence of 2 such classes is merely an over complication.  To cut to the chase - why does it matter if there are two subspecies of human?

Comment: @Mon I am working on that exact topic as we speak… er, type.

Comment: Alright, I added a document to help you out, Mon.

Comment: Please put any relevant information of those species into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Trap it

It sounds like you can't penetrate the shell easily. So, dig a large hole in the ground, camouflage it with some leaves etc. The thing falls in, then assuming it can't climb vertically you just wait until it dies.

Alternatively, catch it in a net, then throw it in the hole and wait until it dies.

Comment: Ideally one would whack the Crabozz with a stick much like a hockey stick, in the direction of the hole.  It may take several whacks to get it into the hole.

Comment: @Willk it is said that if you score a hole in one, you get a prize! The prize being that the hole is a large pan you lift out of the ground and you can cook the Crabozz Lobster style. Jummie!

Answer (score 1):

> In the world of Algennon (which just might be Minecraft converted to a fantasy setting)

You know, all common sense is gone through the window when you mention that.

I don't like playing in creative mode because there is no challenge, but then when I get into survival mode I am the biggest coward ever. I don't enjoy fighting nor hunting, I enjoy the bounty that I get from snuffing everything that moves with as little risk to me as possible.

So, top of my head:

1. Carry a bucket of lava around. Give the little crabs a hot shower when you find them. If you wish to make it even less risky, build a tower of dirt right below you when you see them, attach the lava block to its side and see as the blaze cascade destroys the crabs's home.
2. Run among them to trigger their aggro. Then as you run away, plant a couple blocks of dynamite, run some more, turn around and shoot.
3. If you can walk faster than they can, you can pen them. Build a rock wall around them, then fill with lava.
4. Have an iron golem distract them as you pelt them with arrows.
5. Last I checked a companion wolf or cat can fight monsters for you.
6. If there is foliage around them, setting it ablaze can cause some damage. Even if you don't manage to kill any crabs, you can start a forrest fire which is a sight to see.
7. If you manage to pen a single one between four blocks of dirt, you can use a couple more blocks to have a dirt above the crab. Put gravel or sand above the top block, then remove the block immediately above the crab. The sand or gravel will fall and cause suffocation damage.
8. If they are not impervious to cacti you could try using a block of cactus instead of dirt or anything else to pen them. Some prodding pushes them against the cactus block, which causes damage.
9. If they don't breath underwater, pen them in, build a low ceiling, then pour some water from a hole. If you do this in a place they spawn, you can easily make a farm like this. Some clever tinkering with red sand will allow you to control a floodgate from outside, so you can allow them to spawn on air spaces, then drown them to reap whatever loot they drop.
10. You can dig a huge 20x20x20 space right beneath their spawning point. Leave just one layer of dirt halfway between bedrock and sky. Then punch some holes in the dirt and fill with trap doors (make 2 block wide corridors of trapdoors to ensure some monsters will be over them in a way that they can fall). Connect the trapdoors to a button or switch. Then sit and wait for crabs to spawn, hit the button/switch, and at least some will slip through and die of falling damage (which as far as I remember is different from blunt damage). Then you just have to trek over bedrock to collect the spoils.

Comment: As already clarified, this is not Minecraft. The only elements that are carried over are the two human subspecies, and the amount of monsters.

Comment: @TheSquareCubeLaw Remember that as annoying as it can be, WB:SE doesn't deal with 3rd party worlds. If you think that the answer requires heavy use of some canons, it could be that some clarifications are needed first ^^".

Answer (score 0):

## Use stabbing weapons

For questions like these, the key is to try to use all the information in the question to formulate an answer that satisfies the ask without violating the worldbuilding.

> The shell is very hard and spiky, and most stabbing weapons don’t work on it.

Since most stabbing weapons don’t work, some do. Use the ones that do, instead of the ones that don’t.

Comment: By “most stabbing weapons”, I meant mundane stabbing weapons with no enchantments or acidic coating.

Comment: @Jobah_HigherMind Then I recommend non-mundane stabbing weapons with enchantments or acidic coatings.

Answer (score 0):

**Boil**

[image]

Start a bonfire. Dig a big hole. Fill the hole with water. Drop hot rocks from the bonfire into the pool. When the water boils, lower your Crabozzez gently into the water. An average-sized Crabozz takes eight hours to boil and feeds three dozen people.